# Add GeoJSON layer to OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, geojson, openlayers

I have a GeoJSON file called mygeojson.json and I want to add it as a layer in OpenLayers 3 on top of an openstreetmap layer. So far I could display the openstreetmap world including zoom etc. but for some reason I can't get the mygeojson.json on it.

The geojson contains many polygons and looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13.559093915055664, 52.545214330050563 ], [ 13.559633429050496, 52.545205649772548 ], [ 13.559633415380715, 52.545214636296755 ], [ 13.559093915055664, 52.545214330050563 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

my main.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://ol3js.org/en/master/css/ol.css'>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
    <script src="ol3/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
           new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
           }),
           new ol.layer.Vector({
              title: 'added Layer',
              source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                 projection : 'EPSG:4326',
                 url: 'mygeojson.json'
              })
           })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center:[52.5243700 , 13.4105300],
          zoom:2

        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried removing the projection info but no use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you define your vector source, put the projection setting pointing to the target coordinate reference system (see [the docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/apidoc/ol.source.GeoJSON.html?unstable=true)):

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'added Layer',
      source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
         projection : 'EPSG:3857',
         url: 'mygeojson.json'
      })
  })
```

Look at this example (using your sample data): http://jsfiddle.net/zzahmbff/4/

Perhaps this resource can help you to see different ways to load vector data: http://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter03_03_vector_source.html

Comment: thanks, it worked! Would I still have to do that if mygeojson.json was in EPSG:3857 ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Syntax has changed, see @sevenboarder answer .

Answer (score 20):

FYI... I believe this has changed for OL3 V3.5.0, so gcarrillo's answer would be:

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'added Layer',
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
         url: 'mygeojson.json',
         format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
      })
  })
```

You can see the changes here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#v350

Answer (score 8):

The OpenLayers Vector API is changing a lot. I have a working sample with OpenLayers 3.16.0.

It's important that you must define `featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'` in the options of `readFeatures` like this:

```
.readFeatures(_geojson_object, { featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' })
```

Reference can be found at https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#v350

### Example:

```
_geojson_vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(_geojson_object, { featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' })
});

_geojson_vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: _geojson_vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction
});

map.addLayer(_geojson_vectorLayer);
```

Note: styleFunction

```
var image = new ol.style.Circle({
  radius: 5,
  fill: null,
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 1 })
});

var styles = {
  'Point': new ol.style.Style({
    image: image
  }),
  'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'green',
      width: 1
    })
  }),
  'MultiLineString': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'green',
      width: 1
    })
  }),
  'MultiPoint': new ol.style.Style({
    image: image
  }),
  'MultiPolygon': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'yellow',
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)'
    })
  }),
  'Polygon': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      lineDash: [4],
      width: 3
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    })
  }),
  'GeometryCollection': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'magenta',
      width: 2
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'magenta'
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 10,
      fill: null,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'magenta'
      })
    })
  }),
  'Circle': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'red',
      width: 2
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
    })
  })
};

var styleFunction = function (feature) {
  return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};
```