# Problems with calling GeoJson properties in OpenLayers3 (v3.1.1.)

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have a problem, property from GeoJson is not recognizable by OpenLayers3. 
Debbuger says: Uncaught ReferenceError: feature is not defined on line futher below in OpenLayers3 code:

```
var icon = feature.get("icon");
```

**GeoJson**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    12.231,
                    30.342
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "temperature": "21.1",
                "icon": "4"
            }
        },...
```

**OpenLayers3 v.3.1.1.**

```
var icon = feature.get("icon");
var styleTemperature = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: 'http://prognoza.hr/metsimboli/' + icon + '.gif'
})
      });

var weatherLayer=new ol.layer.Vector({
        layer:'weather',
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.GeoJSON ({
                   projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                   url: 'path/to/geojson.geojson'
        }),
        style: styleTemperature
});
```

Can somebody suggest me something?

EDIT:

This part of the code works, but there is no added style to it, or should I say style is default:

```
var weatherLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        layer:'weather',
        source: new ol.source.GeoJSON ({
                projection: 'EPSG:3765',
                url: 'path/to/file.geojson'
        })
});
```

Comment: Where and how are you defining your feature?

Comment: I thought its going to be defined through var icon... but its not. Can you suggest me how to define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load your style using a style function ([API reference](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.StyleFunction)) similar to this:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'path/to/file.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src: 'http://prognoza.hr/metsimboli/' + feature.get("icon") + '.gif'
        })
    });
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lars_fiddle/1je502Lr/4/)

Comment: I have tried different variations...i dont know why but you suggestion is not working...can you please take a look at the code again...it only works without "style".

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle example

Comment: Thank you on that! This really actually works, but what if the source of geojson is in external file?

Comment: This should help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134688/add-geojson-layer-to-openlayers-3

Comment: Thanks Lars! In the meanwhile I found nice example: http://plnkr.co/edit/GvdVNE?p=preview. But what happened is that modified, downloaded and locally opened files from this plnkr site wouldnt read geojson file in Chrome, but in Firefox geojson was preety much visible. So I am still solving that problem. Any idea on that?