# Get error when I try to display a GeoJson file with Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I get some errors when I try to add a Geojson file with Opelayers 3.

I did follow the first answer here : [Add GeoJSON layer to OpenLayers 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134688/add-geojson-layer-to-openlayers-3)

But I got the following error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp64/www/Web%20Mapping/fond.geojson. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Fr (ol.js:494)
    at Nr.l.ja (ol.js:494)
    at up.<anonymous> (ol.js:331)
    at ad (ol.js:43)
    at io.l.dispatchEvent (ol.js:41)
    at so (ol.js:322)
    at io.l.en (ol.js:321)
    at io.l.Wg (ol.js:321)
```

this is my code :

```
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.js"></script>

    </head>
    <center>
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </center> 
<script>      
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                  url: 'fond.geojson',
                  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
                })
              });
        var map = new ol.Map({
          layers: [
        vectorLayer
          ],
          target: document.getElementById('mapid'),
          view: new ol.View({
            center: [-1095791.453557, 3422374.879112],
            maxZoom: 19,
            zoom: 5
          })
        });
</script>
```

I tried changing the url to :

```
http://localhost/Web%20Mapping/fond.geojson
```

And I get another error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/Web%20Mapping/fond.geojson. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: you need to set the cross origin header

Comment: @iant i did modify my code

Comment: Same again. you need to set cross origin header.

Comment: I don"t know what do you mean?

Comment: The problem isn't due to anything geospatial. You've encountered a common problem with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing restrictions. You'll have better luck looking through similar CORS issues on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/Web%20Mapping/fond.geojson. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer
Goto IIS Manager and
Try to add below value in HTTP Response for virtual folder (enter inetmgr in run command)
Name:  Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Value: *

Comment: on the right track no doubt, but server is I think Apache HTTP, not IIS, hint here is `WAMP`