# Loading external local GeoJSON file in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, html

How do I load GeoJSON file, which is in my laptop, into my HTML code to include some features into my OpenLayers map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load it into a vector source with an URL relative to the location of your Javascript/HTML file:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: "layers/features.geojson",
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
```

See [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can refre this answer [Solved Answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134688/add-geojson-layer-to-openlayers-3).

You can include openlayers-3 in your html code and include the following code

```
var gjson_source=new ol.source.Vector({
                    url: "geojson.txt,      
                    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
                    })
var gjson = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: gjson_source
                    });     
                    map.addLayer(gjson);
```

url will be your Geojson file but extension as txt.

Pleaser refer [Geojson Example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html)